# RIG VEDA Texts Question

Tags: vedas, rig-veda, sanskrit, ayurveda

I was listening to this beautiful video

https://youtu.be/sMHeBEVnKL8

I found these parts :

1) Gananam Tva Ganapatim -  from Rig Veda (2.23.1)

2) After that become :

**praNo devee saraswatee vaajebhirvaajineevatee | dheenaamavitryavatu || 4 ||**

wich i found in II saraswatee sooktam (rigveda samhitaa)

Then the video finish with part 5/11 (what i am interested into)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o1m2Z9LR1ww

After the saraswatee sooktam , what is the text chanted in part 5/11?

Thank you in advance for help

Also , someone can translate in english :

**praNo devee saraswatee vaajebhirvaajineevatee | dheenaamavitryavatu || 4 ||**

Comment: Thank you, i tried already to search the text of Suresha Paddhati but i didn’t found it. So i extracted the first two parts as wrote above. (basecally saraswatee sooktam ends exactly at the end of the 4/11 video. )So after that starts another part as you can see in the 5/11 video. My question was to find and extract these parts of this last video. ( and possible the translation) because i don’t know what is the meaning of the saraswatee sooktam verse above. I am studying but i would like to understand the sansckrit. For example, the first part of  Gananam Tva Ganapatim was easy to find on web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was mentioned in the description part of the video

> It is a form of Vedic jugalbandi called Suresha Paddhati. It is a
>   method of reciting Samhita and other Vikrutis, like Ghana Patha from
>   more than 1 Veda. In this case Rig Veda and Krishna Yajur Veda are
>   recited immediately and simultaneously, to highlight the difference in
>   svara, pada, the place of its occurrences and the sandhi and grammar
>   rules of the respective Vedas. It also seems that there is a verbal
>   competition between the Vedas that are recited.

[Rig Veda 6.61.4](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv06061.htm) provides this Mantra.

> pra ṇo devī sarasvatī vājebhirvājinīvatī | dhīnāmavitryavatu ||
>
> May the divine Sarasvatī, rich in her wealth, protect us well,
>   Furthering all our thoughts with might

Comment: Thank you!! That solved the first part